# Does catboost have a maximum number of categories?

Tags: categorical-data, catboost

I am considering trying to model a very large number of categories. I read that catboost has an algorithm to convert categories to ordered floats to optimize decision tree splits. Does the algorithm have a maximum number of categories that it supports? Also any advice on using it with large number of categories would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Catboost [documentation](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/parameter-tuning) does not mention a specific upper limit, so I think you are only bounded by your RAM if the number of categories is really large.

There is a mention of 255 categories, but this refers to the *default value* chosen in a specific scenario rather than the maximum value.